# Getting Error Message while using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, chatbot, tflearn

I have installed tensorflow with the pip command. But whenever I try to use it in my code by importing it gives me error. I can't figure out why I am getting this error. Also am unable to use tflearn. Also I just have started coding in python recently. Here's the error message :

Proper view : https://justpaste.it/56znr

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Aaman\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "C:\Users\Aaman\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "C:\Users\Aaman\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
File "C:\Users\Aaman\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
File "C:\Users\Aaman\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\Aaman\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
from tensorflow_core import *
File "C:\Users\Aaman\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
File "C:\Users\Aaman\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
module = self._load()
File "C:\Users\Aaman\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
File "C:\Users\Aaman\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "C:\Users\Aaman\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "C:\Users\Aaman\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Aaman\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "C:\Users\Aaman\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "C:\Users\Aaman\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
File "C:\Users\Aaman\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
File "C:\Users\Aaman\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors
```

Here's how I checked if it was installed properly :

```
C:\Users\Aaman>pip show tensorflow     
Name: tensorflow     
Version: 2.1.0       
Summary: TensorFlow is an open source machine learning framework for everyone.   
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/     
Author: Google Inc.      
Author-email: packages@tensorflow.org        
License: Apache 2.0        
Location: c:\users\aaman\anaconda3\envs\chatbot\lib\site-packages      
Requires: protobuf, scipy, keras-applications, keras-preprocessing, absl-py, tensorboard, wrapt, opt-einsum, google-pasta, astor, numpy, tensorflow-estimator, six, wheel, grpcio, gast, termcolor
Required-by:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download and install/update the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019 Redistributable (x64) from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads).

If you are facing any other issues possible reasons are

- Your CPU does not support AVX2 instructions
- Your CPU/Python is on 32 bits
- There is a library that is in a different location/not installed on your system that cannot be loaded.

Please refer tested build configurations for windows [CPU](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#cpu) and [GPU](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu).